# Windows Server internet time server reset after restart

Tags: windows, ntp, time

I encountered an issue with Windows Server 2012 (running as a virtual machine), after an unplanned restart: the original internet time server - time-b.nist.gov - changed to time.windows.com. This set the time of the server with two hours ahead, and caused some issues with a data sync service.

Do you know if this common to happen?

Is there any way to ensure, that the internet time server will be set back to the original one, in case it's changed (e.g like a scheduled task running at startup) ?

Comment: What virtual-machine host are you using?  Is the VM re-imaged after unplanned restarts or on a schedule?

Comment: The virtual-machine host is VMware. I do not know the answer to the second question, since the servers are at a hosting company, and I cannot communicate with them directly.